# Configuration Content Security Policy with Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders for .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, content-security-policy

My application required to use google fonts. Here the link

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,100|Raleway:400,600,100" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Browser blocked the request due `content security policy`. Then i I'am using [Joonasw.AspNetCore.SecurityHeaders](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore-security-headers). So here is my configurations in **Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    //app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHsts(new HstsOptions(TimeSpan.FromDays(30), includeSubDomains: false, preload: false));

// Use certificate pinning with:
// - 30-day caching period
// - One pin in SHA-256 form
// - Report-Only = Invalid certificate should not be reported, but:
// - Report problems to /hpkp-report
app.UseHpkp(hpkp = >{
    hpkp.UseMaxAgeSeconds(30 * 24 * 60 * 60).AddSha256Pin("nrmpk4ZI3wbRBmUZIT5aKAgP0LlKHRgfA2Snjzeg9iY=").SetReportOnly().ReportViolationsTo("/hpkp-report");
});

app.UseCsp(csp = >{
    // If nothing is mentioned for a resource class, allow from this domain
    csp.ByDefaultAllow.FromSelf();

    // Allow JavaScript from:
    csp.AllowScripts.FromSelf() //This domain                    
    .From("cdnjs.cloudflare.com").AddNonce(); //<----;
    // CSS allowed from:
    csp.AllowStyles.FromSelf().From("fonts.googleapis.com").From("fonts.gstatic.com").AddNonce(); //<----;
    csp.AllowImages.FromSelf();

    // HTML5 audio and video elemented sources can be from:
    csp.AllowAudioAndVideo.FromNowhere();

    // Contained iframes can be sourced from:
    csp.AllowFrames.FromNowhere(); //Nowhere, no iframes allowed
    // Allow AJAX, WebSocket and EventSource connections to:
    csp.AllowConnections.To("ws://localhost:1591").To("http://localhost:1591").ToSelf();

    // Allow fonts to be downloaded from:
    csp.AllowFonts.FromSelf().From("fonts.googleapis.com").From("fonts.gstatic.com");

    // Allow object, embed, and applet sources from:
    csp.AllowPlugins.FromNowhere();

    // Allow other sites to put this in an iframe?
    csp.AllowFraming.FromNowhere(); // Block framing on other sites, equivalent to X-Frame-Options: DENY
    //// Do not block violations, only report
    //// This is a good idea while testing your CSP
    //// Remove it when you know everything will work
    //csp.SetReportOnly();
    //// Where should the violation reports be sent to?
    //csp.ReportViolationsTo("/csp-report");
    // Do not include the CSP header for requests to the /api endpoints
    csp.OnSendingHeader = context = >{
        context.ShouldNotSend = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

app.Use((context, next) = >{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";

    return next();
});

app.UseCors("api");

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints = >{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c = >{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
});
```

But is still show the same error. Here the screenshot

[image: Browser]

Here the request sample, not sure why no security header inject on the request

[image: Request sample]

Did I do wrong configuration? Using .net core 3.1

Comment: Library author here. Quite odd that those other values are not showing up in CSP. To enable nonces, you need to add `services.AddCsp();` to your `ConfigureServices()`, and also add `asp-add-nonce="true"` to each inline script you want to have a nonce. (https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore-security-headers#nonces)

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the CSP to be set on the page that loads the css file as a resource? And why do you define HPKP? Even though it is removed from most major browsers it is still very scary to hard code HPKP, especially with only one cert. Your asking for self DoS.

Answer (score 1):

At least for the blocked calls you need to specify separate allow for fonts like below:

```
csp.AllowFonts.FromSelf().From("https://fonts.googleapis.com").From("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/");
```

and also

```
csp.AllowStyles.FromSelf().AllowUnsafeInline().From("https://fonts.googleapis.com")
```

For styles you can use bringed up above AllowUnsafeInline() and if scripts generate the eval error you might try .AllowUnsafeEval()